# docker-compose up fails with conflict for non-existent container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a strange case where `docker-compose up` fails due to a "conflict" with a container ID that does not exist according to the output of `docker ps -a`.

I don't even know how to debug this. Here is my session:

## docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS     NAMES
2d054b76d2a0   gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   6 days ago   Up 5 days             gitlab-runner-bootstrap
```

## docker-compose up

```
Creating network "streamcontrolservice_default" with the default driver
Creating redis                ... error
Creating streamcontrolservice ... 

Creating streamcontrolservice ... done

ERROR: for redis  Cannot create container for service redis: Conflict. The container name "/redis" is already in use by container "57d5a784f5e49ec597350b8f0716ca0900c5ab40fe4e540037697ec8203497b1". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

## docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS     NAMES
2d054b76d2a0   gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   6 days ago   Up 5 days             gitlab-runner-bootstrap
```

## docker-compose ps

```
        Name               Command        State          Ports        
----------------------------------------------------------------------
streamcontrolservice   /start-reload.sh   Up      0.0.0.0:2000->80/tcp
```

## docker-compose top

```
streamcontrolservice
UID     PID    PPID    C   STIME   TTY     TIME                                                                      CMD                                                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
root   22235   22218   0   11:10   ?     00:00:00   /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/uvicorn --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --log-level info main:app                             
root   22295   22235   0   11:10   ?     00:00:00   /usr/local/bin/python -c from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(4)                                                   
root   22296   22235   1   11:10   ?     00:00:00   /usr/local/bin/python -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=5, pipe_handle=7) --multiprocessing-fork
```

## docker-compose config

```
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:6.0.9-alpine
    ports:
    - published: 6379
      target: 6379
    restart: always
  streamcontrolservice:
    build:
      context: /home/myuser/streamcontrolservice
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /start-reload.sh
    container_name: streamcontrolservice
    environment:
      WEB_CONCURRENCY: '1'
    image: somerepo.com:1234/streamcontrolservice:development
    ports:
    - 0.0.0.0:2000:80/tcp
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /home/myuser/streamcontrolservice/app:/app:rw
version: '3.8'
```

## docker rm 57d5a784f5e49ec597350b8f0716ca0900c5ab40fe4e540037697ec8203497b1

```
Error: No such container: 57d5a784f5e49ec597350b8f0716ca0900c5ab40fe4e540037697ec8203497b1
```

What can I do to investigate this further?

Comment: It looks like your `docker` commands are not talking to the same docker daemon as your `docker-compose` commands... Are you running those in the same terminal with the exact same environment variables ? Wouldn't you possibly have a `.env` file in your compose folder defining some daemon to connect to (e.g. `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://some_remote_daemon`)

Comment: Can you `docker rm redis`, ignoring the specific container ID?  If you remove the explicit `container_name:` settings and let Compose pick its own (different) name, does it help?